# Zoom out of website when using RSelenium without changing page size/resolution

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rselenium

I'd like to zoom out of RSelenium remote, but this is surprisingly difficult to find a solution.
I am aware of

- [How to zoom out page using RSelenium library in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266019/how-to-zoom-out-page-using-rselenium-library-in-r), but I woud like to *not* adjust the page size or the resolution---simply zoom out.
- I have pondered sending `control` + `substract` simultaneously, but this is also not quite working. I have taken a look at [How to press two keys simultaneously (i.e., control-s) in a webpage using RSelenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322715/how-to-press-two-keys-simultaneously-i-e-control-s-in-a-webpage-using-rselen), which as the OP noted, `control` + `a` worked but not `control` + `s`, and subsequently `control` + `substract` didn't work either.
- I also tried the Unicode method specified in [How to send simultaneous keys in RSelenium ALT+S to web driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45615659/how-to-send-simultaneous-keys-in-rselenium-alts-to-web-driver/56463248#56463248), which did not work either.

```
library(RSelenium)
driver <- rsDriver()
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("https://www.google.com/")
webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "html")
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "control", "-"))              ## Does not work
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "control", key = "subtract")) ## Does not work
```

The browser is Chrome.

Comment: Which browser are you controlling with RSelenium?

Comment: @AllanCameron I mention that it is Chrome, but the result does not differ with other browsers.

Comment: @Kim Can you try with JS. these 2 lines :  **script <- "document.body.style.zoom='100%'"
remDr$executeScript(script, args = list())**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with sending the keys to the browser, since as noted in the linked posts, it is possible to send `control + a` to the browser window to select elements. It seems rather that the keys are not being recognised as commands to the browser *application*.

There are other ways round this problem however.

As @Muzzamil suggests, you can get a similar effect with changing the css of the document body using Chrome, though this doesn't work in Firefox.

If you want to natively change the browser zoom in a way that persists throughout the session, I can demonstrate solutions using Firefox and Chrome, since in both cases one can navigate to the html-based options page and interact with it to set the browser zoom level.

Here's how you do it with Firefox:

```r
library(RSelenium)

zoom_firefox <- function(client, percent)
{
  store_page <- client$getCurrentUrl()[[1]]
  client$navigate("about:preferences")
  webElem <- client$findElement("css", "#defaultZoom")
  webElem$clickElement()
  webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(as.character(percent)))
  webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "return"))
  client$navigate(store_page)
}
```

This allows the following:

```
driver <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox")
client <- driver$client
client$navigate("https://www.google.com")
client$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

We can see the default zoom is set (100%):

[image]

Now we zoom out to 50% like this:

```r
zoom_firefox(client, 50)
client$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

[image]
And zoom back in like this:

```r
zoom_firefox(client, 100)
client$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

[image]

It's harder with Chrome because its options page uses a complex, nested shadow DOM. Since we can't get an xpath or css selectors to navigate a shadow dom, we need to extract the element's webdriver id using javascript and then force this Id onto another web element which we can then control.

```
zoom_chrome <- function(client, percent)
{
  store_page <- client$getCurrentUrl()[[1]]
  client$navigate("chrome://settings/")
  webElemId <- client$executeScript(paste0("return document.querySelector",
                                           "(\"body > settings-ui\").",
                                           "shadowRoot.querySelector(\"#main\")",
                                           ".shadowRoot.querySelector",
                                           "(\"settings-basic-page\")",
                                           ".shadowRoot.querySelector",
                                           "(\"#basicPage > ",
                                           "settings-section:nth-child(8)",
                                           "> settings-appearance-page\")",
                                           ".shadowRoot.querySelector",
                                           "(\"#zoomLevel\");"),
                                    args = list("dummy"))
  webElem <- client$findElement("css", "html")
  webElem@.xData$elementId <- as.character(webElemId)
  webElem$clickElement()
  webElem$sendKeysToElement(list("3"))
  zooms <- c(25, 33, 50, 67, 75, 8:11 * 10, 125, 150, 175, 200, 250, 3:5 * 100)
  desired_zoom <- which.min(abs(percent - zooms))
  current_zoom <- which(zooms == 300)
  n_keys <- desired_zoom - current_zoom
  if(n_keys > 0) 
    for(i in seq(n_keys)) 
      webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "down_arrow"))
  if(n_keys < 0) 
    for(i in seq(abs(n_keys))) 
      webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "up_arrow")) 
  webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(as.character(percent)))
  webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "return"))
  client$navigate(store_page)
}
```

But it works in the same way:

```
driver <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever = "80.0.3987.106")
client <- driver$client
client$navigate("https://www.google.com")
client$screenshot(display = TRUE)
zoom_chrome(client, 50)
client$screenshot(display = TRUE)
zoom_chrome(client, 100)
client$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

Which gives exactly the same results as firefox.

Of course, you could easily write a simple wrapper function that selects which "zoom" function to call based on the current browser.

I have not looked into implementing this in internet explorer or phantomjs since they do not have html-based options pages.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you for such detailed answer on the question. Works perfectly.

Comment: To get low percents like 30% on firefox it's easiest to click 3 twice, so i.e. to set to 30%:                                                                    
```remDr$navigate("about:preferences");
webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "#defaultZoom");
webElem$clickElement();
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(as.character(3)));
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(as.character(3)));
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "return"))```

Answer (score 3):

You can try Zoom out with `Java script`. Please try below code for zoom out at 90%.

```
library(RSelenium)
driver <- rsDriver()
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("https://www.google.com/")
webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "html")
script <- "document.body.style.zoom='90%'" 
remDr$executeScript(script, args = list())
```